# How to play a known frequency sound in java

Tags: java, spring, javasound

I found a snippet of code here or online and have been using it to play a sound. The problem is that for frequencies out of human range and even upper level human range there appears to be a substitution of the sound frequency into an audible one. In other words instead of being very high accurate pitched frequency it suddenly plays a random tone that we can hear. The ranges I am interested in are 15,000Hz to 30,000Hz. I don't fully understand this code and would like some help.

```
public static void tone(int hz, int msecs, double vol) throws LineUnavailableException {        
    byte[] buf = new byte[1];
    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE,8,1,true,false);     
    SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl.open(af);
    sdl.start();
    for (int i=0; i < msecs*8; i++) {
          double angle = i / (SAMPLE_RATE / hz) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
          buf[0] = (byte)(Math.sin(angle) * 127.0 * vol);
          sdl.write(buf,0,1);
    }
    sdl.drain();
    sdl.stop();
    sdl.close();
}
```

What I have done is make a form with a button on it and it calls a sound class

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{     
       Sound.tone(15000,2000,1);
    }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}   
}
```

The sound class code is:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Sound { 
    public static float SAMPLE_RATE = 8000f;

    public static void tone(int hz, int msecs) throws LineUnavailableException {
        tone(hz, msecs, 1.0);
    }

    public static void tone(int hz, int msecs, double vol) throws LineUnavailableException {
    
        byte[] buf = new byte[1];
        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE,8,1,true,false);     
        SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        sdl.open(af);
        sdl.start();
        for (int i=0; i < msecs*8; i++) {
            double angle = i / (SAMPLE_RATE / hz) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            buf[0] = (byte)(Math.sin(angle) * 127.0 * vol);
            sdl.write(buf,0,1);
        }
        sdl.drain();
        sdl.stop();
        sdl.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "In other words instead of being very high accurate pitched frequency it suddenly plays a random tone that we can hear" Are you aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing?

Comment: As @AndyTurner says, with an 8KHz sample rate, you can only reproduce frequencies under 4KHz.

Comment: Also note that many speakers will not be designed to output such high frequencies.

Comment: The problem most certainly is aliasing, as @AndyTurner says. You could go higher if you chose the sample rate of 44100. This would allow you to get up to just over 22K which is inaudible for us humans. 44100 FPS is very common, and is known as "CD Quality" if there is also 16 bit resolution instead of 8 as you have, and stereo instead of mono. This format is supported by Java.